# Statistics of histogram created from weighted data - numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, statistics

I have a 2 arrays of data such that one describes the data I want to plot, and the second describes the frequency or weight of that data.

I create a histogram using

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [7., 8.2, 9.6, 11.3, 13.2, 15.5, 18.1, 21.2, 24.9, 29.1, 34.1, 40.0]
freq = [2., 4.1, 4.5, 3.2, 2.7, 2.1, 1.3, 1., 0.9, 0., 0., 0.]

h = np.histogram(data, weights = freq, bins = data)
f = plt.hist(data, weights = freq, bins = data)
```

I now want to find the mean, standard deviation, skewness and kurtosis of the resulting histogram, but because the data is "weighted" or pre-counted, I cant seem to get the scipy.stats.describe function to work. Any ideas?

I should make it clear, I have tried scipy.stats.describe but cant seem to find a weight argument that allows me to do what I want. I dont really know what tools are available to help with this, and google searches aren't returning many helpful results (though I admit I may be searching for the wrong thing).

To make matters a touch more complicated, the eagle eyed of you will have noticed that the data is spread evenly in log space, not real space. So if your method involves gaussian fitting, you may want to bear that in mind...

Comment: "So if your method involves gaussian fitting, you may want to bear that in mind..." ... Are we being graded?

Comment: I was simply pointing out that if someone wanted to come back with a method of fitting to the data, that the data is spaced in log space, which would affect the fit. No need to get snarky.

Comment: Usually it is expected that the Questioner will provide some form of what they have tried before asking for contributions... I take your point though, being snarky never helped anyone!

Comment: Sorry, I should make it a little more obvious that I have tried to find a way to use the scipy.stats.describe tool, only to find it is lacking the arguments I need to specify my data in the correct way. That said, its functioning exactly as intended, I am just not wanting to use it how it should be used! Ill make it clearer now.

Comment: The question seems to be "How to compute statistical moments from a histogram?". In this case it would be better placed at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can I ask why you think its better placed there? I know the mathematics of how to calculate statistics from a histogram, and I can, theoretically, do this one on paper, but my issue is I need to get python to do it. For a touch of context, I have an astronomical 3d image in PPT space. For each PP pixel, there is a 12 slice temperature scale with a brightness associated with it. The temp scale is the data, the brightness is the weight. I am trying to get it to work with 1 pixel, before I create a loop and generate 4,000,000 histograms and data sets.

Comment: @AlexHoward The way you phrased the question conveyed a certain sense of ignorance on the topic of the statistical methodology involved. This concern appears to be unfounded, but then I do not quite understand why you are unable to do it in code if you can do it on paper.

Comment: Fair enough. I can do it in code I supposed this one time. But it would be slow, inelegant, and likely a waste of resources. I am sure there must be a way to do it with a prebuilt package. I cant be the first person with a list of data and a list of weights to want to know the kurtosis of the resultant histogram.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is so simple that you can write your own function here and don't need a function from scipy.stats. Basically what you have given here is the distribution function and want to calculate expectation values. Which is given by a simple integral. An example for a solution would be

```
def integrator(f,data,freq):
    diffs = np.roll(data,-1)-data
    return (f(data[:-1])*freq[:-1]*diffs[:-1]).sum()

freq_norm = freq/integrator(lambda x:1,data,freq)

exp_x = integrator(lambda x:x,data,freq_norm)
exp_x2 = integrator(lambda x:x**2,data,freq_norm)
exp_x4 = integrator(lambda x:x**4,data,freq_norm)

mean = exp_x
kurt = integrator(lambda x: ((x-exp_x)/std)**4,data,freq_norm)
skew = integrator(lambda x: ((x-exp_x)/std)**3,data,freq_norm)
```

Comment: This looks good. Shame its not contained somewhere, but that IS what I want. Just wanted to check, should kurt be that or over (exp_x2 - exp_x**2)**2? And if I want Skewness, do I simply add exp_x3 to the list and repeat with that?

Comment: The kurtosis in my example is wrong. You can calculate it with integrator(lambda x: ((x-exp_x)/std)**4,data,freq_norm). Skewness can be calculated with the same expression by changing the exponent from 4 to 3.

Comment: @AlexHoward are the two of you sure this is correct? Scaling with the interval width is correct if your `freq` are (up to normalisation) _densities_. If they are _bin counts_ it is not.

Comment: In all honesty, not at all sure. They are bin counts, not densities.

Comment: @PaulPanzer You are perfectly right. I was assuming densities. If they are bin counts you should remove the scaling with the width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scipy.stats.rv_histogram to generate a random variable whose distribution is given by the output of numpy.histogram, then use the stats method on it to get what you want.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

data = [7., 8.2, 9.6, 11.3, 13.2, 15.5, 18.1, 21.2, 24.9, 29.1, 34.1, 40.0]
freq = [2., 4.1, 4.5, 3.2, 2.7, 2.1, 1.3, 1., 0.9, 0., 0., 0.]

rv = stats.rv_histogram(np.histogram(data, weights=freq))
```

You can also directly get the (non-central) moments with `rv.moments(n)` where `n` is the order you're interested in.
mean, var, skew, kurt = rv.stats(moments='mvsk')

I hope this might help someone!